# If any string exists in the computer name, the condition should be set to true

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to check if a Computer name has BKUP, NAS, PLAYER, or BACKUP in any part of its name through a batch script. If the condition is true I will run an additional command to create a network share on that computer.

This is my batch file:

```
echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM skip lines 1 read lines 2 in PRORGRAMS OUTPUT
@For /F "skip=1 tokens=1" %%u IN ('WMIC computersystem get name^) do (
SET "TRUE="
    IF x%%u BKUP    TRUE=1
    IF x%%u NAS     TRUE=1
    IF x%%u PLAYER  TRUE-1
    IF x%%u BACKUP  TRUE=1
```

Comment: I am asking for the correct method of scripting.

Comment: The easiest way is probably `IF NOT "%COMPUTERNAME%"=="%COMPUTERNAME:BKUP=%" SET TRUE=1`, etc. You don't need to use the `FOR` loop this way since you don't need `WMIC`. Take a look at [this](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html).